# How do you escape a space in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

I have an object like this:

```
foo = {"Foo Bar":"bar","Foo":"Bar"};
```

In my Jade template I have:

```
p 1: {{foo.Foo Bar}}
p 2: {{foo.Foo}}
```

Problem is, the output is:

```
1: {{foo.Foo Bar}} 
2: Bar
```

But it should be:

```
1: bar
2: Bar
```

Why is this problem happening? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it like this

```
p 1: {{foo["Foo Bar"]}}
```

Comment: Thanks. But... why? Why do they care if there's a space in the property name? Why can't you just have a two-char escape character for the space, which would be three times more efficient than having to add three extra chars?

Comment: @CommaToast Since this is relating to javascript object, it is a nature of javascript that the field name is tokenized by space. So if it contains a space, they you can access by given "Key"

Answer (score 1):

Angular JS or anywhere the way to access a property name **with spaces** you need to use the `[]` notation like this

```
Object["key name"]
```

so in your case it will be

```
foo["Foo Bar"]
```